# How to fix "server shell request failed on channel 0" on Windows 11 OpenSSH default shell?

Tags: windows, ssh, shell, openssh, windows-11

Every time I connect to my Windows 11 SSH server, It keeps getting an error saying "server shell request failed on channel 0".

[image: console]

I ensured that the default shell is specified properly

[image]

My computer has enough resources and I can start the shell by specifying it after the command:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

For reference, I am using the default config: https://pastebin.com/Zh94fyT5

and my .ssh folder is empty.

Comment: But you're starting a different shell here. Can you start the _same_ shell that's configured?

Comment: Post your OpenSSH server configuration file.

Comment: @user1686 same effect. I will update my question

Comment: @Ramhound It is the default. I can only find sshd_config_default, in which everything is commented out

Comment: I have the solution but in order to know it’s relevant I must see the configuration file.

Comment: @Ramhound I posted a pastebin of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had updated from Windows 10 to 11, but I guess the "OpenSSH server" service remained old. By removing all OpenSSH instances and reinstalling (through enabling the optional feature), I fixed the issue.

1. Ensure that there is only one installation of the OpenSSH server on your machine.
2. Try reinstalling OpenSSH. Ensure that uninstall removes all previous configurations.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had by accident installed the Win32 version, installing Win64 version of OpenSSH server solved this exact error message.

Comment: This is exactly what help to resolved the problem. Thank you!